# How to create thumbnail of any file format in asp.net?

Tags: web, c#, asp.net

I am trying to create thumbnail of .docx, .excel, .pdf etc many format.

I have problem how to create thumbnail of dynamic content in web form of asp.net.

Comment: dynamic content?

Comment: dynamic content means file content was uploaded on database and according to file format that again display

Answer (score 0):

You can use libraries like ABCPdf that allows you to generate previews from files on the fly, please note that you may need to use different libraries for different file types.